How is this oil suction gun meant to be used?

Honda Civic coupe 2000.
I bought this oil suction gun a long time ago thinking that it was to suck oil out of the engine incase you had overfilled it. I thought you are meant to push it into the hole where the engine oil dipstick goes and then pull it out.
However what I found was that the diameter of the pipe was too big it would not go in the dipstick hole.   It may not fit around the dipstick pipe either I didn’t manage to slide it on - I would also have to remove the exhaust manifold to see if I had any chance of putting it on but I have a feeling it’s to small to fit around either.
Is this just not fit for purpose or am I using it the wrong way/purpose?  Perhaps it is meant to take oil from a container and then cleanly put through the engine oil filler cap hole instead of using a funnel and that was the point of this product? Personally I think the funnel takes less space and is easier to use and clean.
And maybe it can be used for brake fluid and coolant but it’s unlikely you overfill those.
So looks like a useless product may aswell chuck it is there some use for this?
Thanks
